# Issue with view controller not releasing memory

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm working on an app where different view controllers get pushed and dismissed via dismissModalViewControllerAnimated.

I'm having some memory issues with the app just crashing after a while. Looking at the Leaks instrument, I see that my overall allocations keeps going up and up. Even after the viewcontroller is dismissed, memory does not go down.

Are there any obvious reasons for this? What is the simplest and easiest way to find out why my app is crashing? Thanks

**POSSIBLE SOLUTIONS**

I went through some trial and error as well as googling and made a few changes:

1) A delegate relationship may have been retaining the viewController, so I changed the object's delegate property to weak.

2) NSTimer's should be invalidated before dismissing viewController.

3) UIView animations may interfere with dealloc being called? You can use `[view.layer removeAllAnimations]` to end them before popping your viewController.

Comment: Try running Analyze and see if that picks up anything. Also, on a side note `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated` is deprecated, use `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:<(BOOL)> completion:<^(void)completion>];`

Comment: Thanks, Analyze didn't pick anything up, and I'm now using the new dismiss method. Any other ideas?

Comment: Then, confirm if `dealloc` is being called (eg through `NSLog` or breakpoint. If not, then probably a strong reference cycle or some other circular logic. If that's not it, then you might want to use instruments to confirm if leak, then what precisely is leaking. It's impossible to diagnose in the abstract. You need to give us clues about what's actually leaking.

Comment: By the way, memory use will not go down if you use things like `imageNamed`, which caches images. We should try to distinguish between memory consumption, leaks, and strong reference cycles. Also, I assume you've run the code through the static analyzer and have no warnings there.

Comment: @Rob Good ideas, I can confirm dealloc is not being called, does this mean an object in the viewController isn't being released properly? Also, what is an alternative way of using imageNamed? Thanks

Comment: Like Rob pointed out, the most likely culprit is probably Strong Reference Cycles. If this is an unfamiliar term, you can read about it [Here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html). But basically it means that A points to B and B points to A with Strong references. Thus neither of them can ever be released under ARC.

Comment: @user339946 Yep, if `dealloc` is not getting called, neither the controller nor its ivars will get released! You probably have a strong reference cycle somewhere. Look for things in your code where you passed a reference of the view controller, itself, to something else. Perhaps a recurring `NSTimer`. Perhaps a GCD block in some background queue that is still running. Could be tons of things. You'll have to dig through your view controller code and think about where you passed `self` as a parameter to some other method. That's the most common type of strong reference cycle.

Answer (score 0):

If your memory is not go down after the `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated` .. it means you are creating the `Global Object` of the `ViewController` And after `dismissing` you are not setting the `Object = nil`;

If you set nil then your memory goes down automatically.